# Encoding Float to RG/RGBA and Blending

Tags: opengl, shaders, directx, glsl, hlsl

Encoding a float value inside a RG or RGBA texture is very interesting and useful but it is also become quite useless when you use blending as the result and the values might be altered because of face overlapping.
Is there a way to avoid such issues ?

here is an example of a bad result when encoding depth on the red and green channels and just decoding it again in a post-process effect.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Disable blending when rendering your depth texture.

Or use an actual depth texture as depth buffer in a frame buffer object then use that depth texture in later passes with a sampler.

Comment: But I need to use blending. This pass is used to store values inside a texture. THis texture will be used inside another pass.

Comment: disable blending when you're writing to that texture, enable blending at other times. You can't blend when writing encoded depth.